# getting blank array when consoled logged out results in nodejs mysql

Tags: sql, node.js

I have this code where I want to check for existing email but I am not able to get the array of all the data containing matched row by SQL.

```
var email = req.body.email;
        var fullname = req.body.fullname;
        var userPassword = req.body.userPassword
        const saltRounds = 10

        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM registeredusers WHERE id = ?' 
        pool.query(sql, email, (err, results) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Internal server error. Retry... '

                })
            }
            else if (results === 1) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Email already exist.',
                    res: results
                })
            }
```

Comment: Which database and which library to connect to the database are you using?

Comment: solved..
I was using bcrypt and mysql

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
let sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM registeredusers WHERE email = ?'
        pool.query(sql, [req.body.email], (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Internal server error. Retry... '
                })
            }
            else if (results[0].cnt > 0) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Email already exist.',
                })
            }
```